# include php package in file instead of composer

Tags: php, include, package, css-parsing

I want to include a php package, a css parser: https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser In installation guide it says to "Add php-css-parser to your composer.json":

```
{
"require": {
        "sabberworm/php-css-parser": "*"
    }
}
```

(I don't even know what composer.json is) Since I need only in one script, is there a way to include it only in a file? Like:

```
<?php
include //something here
//Do stuff with css parser
?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Your best approach would be to familiarize yourself with composer, what it's for and how it works.

You *could* copy the code from the module manually and include it in your project, but why bother?

You should simply need to run `composer require sabberworm/php-css-parser` from your project's root directory. Composer will automatically create the `composer.json` file which defines your project information and its dependencies, and the `composer.lock` file which stores information about the version of each dependency you've installed so you can deploy specific versions to other places.

If you don't have composer installed, check out the [download instructions](https://getcomposer.org/download/).

Once you've installed it, you need to include the composer autoloader and you will be ready to include your custom package:

```
<?php
// Include composer's autoloader
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Now you can use any composer installed package:
$parser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser($sText);
```

Comment: composer can not be used for any web project that is distributed and installed on the final client server, like a WP plugin or a PHP script